# How to identify the multiple button elements having same text using xpath in the below HTML code?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
'''
<span class="Text xyz med">234</span>
<span>
<button class="btn-link" type="button">Hide</button>
</span>
<span class="Text xyz med">2456</span>
<span>
<button class="btn-link" type="button">Hide</button>
</span>
```

My code:

numbers=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Hide"]'

Clicks on the "Hide" for the first element having the text "234"

Can anyone suggest if there an any option to loop through this hide links using xpath.
The only unique identifier here is the numeric value.

Comment: Do you mean, you want unique identifier for each button separatly?

Comment: Yes @Pratik......I tried using :driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="Hide"]' and looping through the list. That didnt help too.

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="Hide"]')[1] and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using index like this:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('(.//button[text()="Hide"])[1]')` - to select 234

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('(.//button[text()="Hide"])[2]')` - to select 2456

Comment: Getting a syntax error: given xpath expression "//button[text()="Hide"][1])" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: Yes you have syntax error - //button[text()="Hide"][1]) not correct , correct is (//button[text()="Hide"])[1]

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//button[text()="Hide"])'[1]) Is this right? iam seeing this error: "either the element is no longer attached to the DOM". If I dont use Index, the syntax is fine. Should i use : find_elements_by_xpath ?

Comment: @Prasad and @Pratik Notice the single quote `'` where it is closing. It should be `driver.find_element_by_xpath('(.//button[text()="Hide"])[2]')`

Comment: @DevThank you. The above syntax worked. Assuming I have 10 links on the page(which may increase), any easy way to loop through all of them? Instead of trying to type driver.find_element_by_xpath('(.//button[text()="Hide"])[10]') . Will appending the links to a List help?